# Simple tab app created by Teams toolkit does not work on Outlook

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, manifest, teams-toolkit

I am trying to create a Teams app extended to Microsoft 365 by following the quick start of this doc: [Extend a Teams personal tab across Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-personal-tab?tabs=manifest-teams-toolkit#quickstart.)

I only want a simple personal tab with an iFrame of my website (which has all the authorization to be embedded).

## Teams toolkit

I'm using the VSC extension Teams toolkit to create this unified manifest.
Debug in Teams works well ✅

However, Debug in Outlook does nothing really work: it's blocked in a loading page → see the screenshot attached.
[Debug in Outlok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hihIn.png)

## Export zip manifest

So I tried to export the manifest in a zip file with the appropriate format inside (see at the end the manifest).

My application and its iFrame :

- ✅ works well in Teams when uploaded in the Teams Admin center
- ✅ works well in Microsoft365 when uploaded through https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?#/Settings/IntegratedApps
- but **is not at all displayed in Outlook for web or in Outlook for Windows** after the previous upload. Windows outlook version 1.2023.719.200.
  [Error in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFe2y.png)

Do you know why the unified manifest I used does not work in Outlook ?
Is there a specific release to wait for to enable this feature (I don't see this information on the learning center).

Does someone have already tried this ?
How did you manage it to work ?
Thank you

Here is the manifest.json extracted from my zip

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Teams App, Inc.",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "tabs-basic-20230807",
        "full": "Full name for tabs-basic-20230807"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description of tabs-basic-20230807",
        "full": "Full description of tabs-basic-20230807"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "index0",
            "name": "Personal Tab",
            "contentUrl": "https://impactco2.fr/iframes/transport?theme=default",
            "websiteUrl": "https://impactco2.fr/iframes/transport?theme=default",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "$https://impactco2.fr"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please try checking if you are facing the same issue with this sample as well? https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2.1.0/todo-list-with-Azure-backend-M365

Comment: I will try it thanks. However it seems more sophisticated, I just need an iFrame

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT still facing the issue (I add the screenshot above) https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFe2y.png

Comment: Could you please make sure you have allowed the required frame ancestors in your CSP header? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-personal-tab?tabs=manifest-teams-toolkit#configure-content-security-policy-headers and in the Authorized client applications section of your app, ensure required Client Id values are added:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-personal-tab?tabs=manifest-teams-toolkit#update-azure-ad-app-registration-for-sso

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT actually even with links from www.openstreetmap.org which allows iFrame I still have the same issue with "Debug in Outlook" (but none with Teams)

Moreover, if I build the manifest and then upload in https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?#/Settings/IntegratedApps, the iFrame works well with Microsft365 interface but nothing appears in the sidebar of Outlook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found after hours of research : **you need to enable `Targeted release for everyone`** on your [Admin Center](https://admin.microsoft.com/#/Settings/OrganizationProfile/:/Settings/L1/ReleasePreferences) > `Org settings` > `Organization profile`

[Picture of the interface to enable early release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glXqu.png)

I don't know why this setting needs to be modified for Outlook and not for Ms365 and Teams...

Anyway, case solved.

Answer (score 0):

Teams Toolkit provides a out-of-box personal tab app with SSO that runs in Teams and Outlook. Could you please create this app and checks if can work well in Outlook from your side?

Follow the steps below to create this app and run it in Outlook.

1. Install the latest version of Teams Toolkit VS Code extension.
2. Run "Teams: Create a New App" from command palette.
3. Select "Tab" -> "React with Fluent UI". Then select the programming language, workspace folder and application name.
4. From "Run and Debug Activity Panel" in VS Code, select "Debug in Outlook" and click the "Run and Debug" green arrow button.

Comment: I just want to display an IFrame, not really re-create a full new application.
However what you proposed works well within Teams debug, but on Outlook I still have .. nothing like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFe2y.png

Comment: Even https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/tab-personal/mvc-csharp/demo-manifest/tab-personal.zip doesn't show in Outlook